# Spring data mongodb throws org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, objectid

I have an object that I want to save to both mysql and mongodb

object class is like:

Order:

```
public long id;
public String brokerID;//UUID
public String userID;//UUID
public String orderID;//UUID
public double price;
public long volume;
```

the long id field is for mysql to auto_increment and return to me as an OUT parameter,

when I am trying to save two different order objects to mongodb with Spring data, it gives me DuplicateKeyException as it assumes id is my key, and since it's not initialized, both objects have id = 0.

```
mongoOperation.insert(new Order(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 500d, 500l));

mongoOperation.insert(new Order(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString(), UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 500d, 500l));
```

How am I able to save it to mongodb, rename id to something else?

Answer (score 0):

OK, change the id to some other name  like mysqlId resolves this issue